# XPath to select an element if previous element contain a matching text() - Python, Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to extract an element if the previous elements text() matches specific criteria. for example,

```
<html>
<div>
<table class="layouttab">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row" class="srb">General information:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>(xxx) yyy-zzzz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row" class="srb">Website:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><a href="http://xyz.edu" target="_blank">http://www.xyz.edu</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row" class="srb">Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>4-year, Private for-profit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row" class="srb">Awards offered:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Less than one year certificate<br>One but less than two years certificate<br>Associate's degree<br>Bachelor's
            degree
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row" class="srb">Campus setting:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>City: Small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row" class="srb">Related Institutions:</td>
        <td><a href="?q=xyz">xyz-New York</a>
            (Parent):
            <ul>
                <li style="list-style:circle">Berkeley College - Westchester Campus</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</html>
```

Now, I want to extract the URL if the previous  element has "Website:  " in text() properties. 
I am using python 2.x with scrapy 0.14. I was able to extract data using individual element such as

```
 item['Header_Type']= site.select('div/table[@class="layouttab"]/tr[3]/td[2]/text()').extract()
```

But this approach fails if the website parameter is missing and the tr[3] shift upward and i get 'Type' in website element and 'Awards offered' in Type.

Is there a specific command in xPath like,

```
'div/table[@class="layouttab"]/tr/td[2] {if td[1] has text = "Website"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For python and scrapy you should use following to select "Type" field,
worked great for me.

```
item['Header_Type']= site.select('div[1]/table[@class="layouttab"]/tr/td[contains(text(),"Type")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 4):

`div/table[@class="layouttab"]\tr\td[text()="Website"]\following-sibling::node()` will work, I think.  Otherwise, you could user `parent` and go to `td[2]` from there.

Answer (score 1):

The following XPath will do:

```
/html/div/table[@class='layouttab']/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'Website')]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
/html/div/table[@class="layouttab"]/tbody/tr/td[. = 'Website:  ']/following-sibling::td/a/text()
```

- Drill down till `td` and see if its text matches `Website:`
- Use `following-sibling` to go to the next `td`
- Drill down to retrieve the `a` and get the URL using `text()`

Answer (score 1):

This will also work.. And is more generic..

```
//table[@class='layouttab']//td[contains(text(),'Website')]/following-sibling::td//text()
```

If there is only one table on the page where u are extracting data then this will also work..

```
//td[contains(text(),'Website')]/following-sibling::td//text()
```